# C# How to show multiple databases tables in one Datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql

I've a datagridview and Show button on my Windows form app. In datagridview, I want to show the tables of multi databases but with my sql code I only show the current databases tables. How can I show all databases' tables?

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG AS 'DATABASE Name', 
       TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'SCHEMA Name', 
       TABLE_NAME AS 'TABLO Name' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: You can do relationships between two datatables in a dataset. If you want to show multiple datatables in a datagridview merge them together or better yet do a UNION or INNER JOIN in your SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL syntax `table1 JOIN table2` to Show multiple tables. If you can't do that use multiple SQL queries to feed a table then set it as `ItemsSource` to your datagrid, the name might be a bit different in Windows.Forms then in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use [SQL Server Undocumented Stored Procedure - sp_MSForEachDB](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16976.aspx?Redirected=true).

Excerpt from the site:

> 6 Common Uses of the undocumented Stored Procedure sp_MSforeachdb
>   http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/6-common-uses-of-undocumented-stored.html
>
> 1. Print all the database names in a SQL Server Instance
> 2. Print all the tables in all the databases of a SQL Server Instance
> 3. Display the size of all databases in a SQL Server instance
> 4. Determine all the physical names and attributes(size,growth,usage) of all databases in a SQL Server instance
> 5. Change Owner of all databases to 'sa'
> 6. Check the Logical and Physical integrity of all objects in the database

```
/* Create temp table to hold result */
Declare @blackFrog as Table
(
    [DATABASE Name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [SCHEMA Name] [sysname] NULL,
    [TABLE Name] [sysname] NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @command varchar(1000) /* create the command you want to execute on all databases */
SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') 
            BEGIN USE ? SELECT TABLE_CATALOG AS ''DATABASE Name'', 
            TABLE_SCHEMA AS ''SCHEMA Name'', TABLE_NAME AS ''TABLE Name'' FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES; END' 

Insert Into @blackFrog EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command;

Select * From @blackFrog
```

[image: Example]

It's best to wrap the whole thing in a stored procedure. **It is strongly recommended to avoid using undocumented features of SQL Server in your Production environment.**